# The multi-part identifier "genLedger.AccountLink" could not be bound. (4104) (SQLExecDirectW)

Tags: python, sql, django, alias

I am getting the below error for the below SQL query, I am pretty sure it has something to do with the Alias given to PostGl. I just don't know how to correct it.

Query:

```
all =  'SELECT Master_Sub_Account , cAccountTypeDescription , Debit , Credit FROM [Kyle].[dbo].[PostGL] AS genLedger'\
                    'Inner JOIN [Kyle].[dbo].[Accounts] '\
                    'on Accounts.AccountLink = genLedger.AccountLink '\
                    'Inner JOIN [Kyle].[dbo].[_etblGLAccountTypes] as AccountTypes '\
                    'on Accounts.iAccountType = AccountTypes.idGLAccountType'\
                    ' WHERE genLedger.AccountLink not in (161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,122)'
```

Error :

> The multi-part identifier "genLedger.AccountLink" could not be bound. (4104)

Comment: Perhaps: `WHERE genLedger.AccountLink NOT IN (161, 162, ...)`?

Comment: It now gives "The multi-part identifier "PostGL.AccountLink" could not be bound. (4104)" as an error when use this code

Comment: There is an alias for the table `PostGL`. `PostGL.AccountLink` should be replaced with `genLedger.AccountLink`.

Comment: @ReinisVerbelis I have edited the above question. The error for the multi-part identifier is still showing

Comment: Then next thing is that there is no space at the end of the first line. Between `genLedger` and `Inner JOIN [Kyle].[dbo].[Accounts]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at where clause its not a valid sql syntax :

```
WHERE genLedger.AccountLink <> 161 OR genLedger.AccountLink <> 162 OR...
```

but you can use `not in` instead:

```
WHERE genLedger.AccountLink not in (161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,122)
```

Comment: It now gives "The multi-part identifier "PostGL.AccountLink" could not be bound. (4104)" as an error when use this code

Comment: @KyleStranger you gave `PostGL` table an alias called "genLedger" and you have to use this alias everywhere instaed